# I am learning to clip a MODIS snow cover dataset with my shapefile in asset and then export the clipped image to drive

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to Google Earth Engine code editor. I want to get an image from GEE for the MODIS SnowCover for an area of a shapefile. The code I tried for the purpose:

```
var snowCover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2021-01-01'));
var snowCover = snowCover.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
var snowCoverVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['black', '0dffff', '0524ff', 'ffffff'],
};

Map.setCenter(84, 29, 6);
Map.addLayer(snowCover, snowCoverVis, 'Snow Cover');
Map.addLayer(roi);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: snowCover,
  description: 'SnowCoverImages',
  assetId: 'exampleExport',
  crs: EPSG 4326,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,
  region: roi,
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4c6c4c5694f22845f6070e087c0acbf2

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (18:13)

How can I correct my code?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to describe the nature of the error in the Question body. Question that don't explain the problem are likely to be closed until they do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this script.

You try to export `snowCover`, which isn't an image, but an image collection. In one way or another, you need to reduce the collection of images down to a single image. Often, a median pixel value is used. But in your case, your collection contains imagery for 20 years, so maybe you're after something else? In any case, the below shows how to get the median (for a single year). Note that I'm filtering out all imagery outside of your `roi` from the collection. That's usually something you want to do.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')
  .filterBounds(roi)
var snowCover = collection
  .select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
  .median()
  .clip(roi)
```

The actual error message you're seeing is because of the `crs` argument in `Export.image.toDrive()`. It must be a string: `EPSG:4326`. The `projection` variable used is also undefined. In most cases, you can simply leave that out, unless you really know that you need it. You're also passing `assetId` as an argument, which only exists on the `toAsset()` method. Maybe you simply can do this to export?

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: snowCover, 
  description: 'SnowCoverImages', 
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e31bfeb154274e53d16114faeadb4e38